# Symfony 1.4 (migration from 1.0): Foreign Keys and the config.yml of an admin module

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm migrating code from Symfony1.0 to Symfony 1.4.
Created a admin module called: **mymodel** using **Propel**.

The database of that model is like this:

```
table: mymodel_table.
  column: fkLabelId
  column: fkRightsOwnerId
NOTE: both are foreing keys.
```

They are connected this way -again in the physical DB-:

```
  fkLabelId        -------> REFER `DB/label`(`id`);

  fkRightsOwnerId  -------> REFER `DB/ownersright`(`id`);
```

Now, I created the admin-module in my project -**cms** in the following code-:

```
php symfony propel:generate-admin cms --module=myModel MyModelTable
```

In my page I can see the info of the table **mymodel_table**, this is: both **id**. But I would like to see the info referenced in the other two tables.

This is the config.yml **OF THE SYMFONY 1.0 VERSION**:

```
generator:
class:              sfPropelAdminGenerator
param:
  model_class:      MyModel
  theme:            default
  fields:
    fk_label_id: {params: disabled=false}
    fk_rightsowner_id: {params: disabled=false}
  list:
    filters:              [fklabelid, _label_filter, fkrightsownerid, _rightsowner_filter]
    peer_method:          doSelectJoinAll
    display:              [=_label_list, =_rightsowner_list]
    actions:
    actions:
      _create:        ~
    object_actions:
      _edit:          ~
      _delete:        ~
  edit:
    display: [=_label_edit, =_rightsowner_edit]
    actions:
      _list:          ~
      _save_and_list: ~
      _save:          ~
      _delete:        ~
```

This is the config.yml **OF THE SYMFONY 1.4 VERSION**:

```
generator:
  class: sfPropelGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           MyModel
    theme:                 admin15
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              MyModel
    plural:                MyModel
    route_prefix:          My_model
    with_propel_route:     1
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

config:
  actions: ~
  fields:
    fk_label_id: {params: disabled=false}
    fk_rightsowner_id: {params: disabled=false}
  list:
    filters:              [fklabelid, _label_filter, fkrightsownerid, _rightsowner_filter] 
  //  peer_method:          doSelectJoinAll                         ("commented")
  //  display:              [=_label_list, =_rightsowner_list]      ("commented")
  filter:  ~
  form:    ~
  edit:    ~
  new:     ~
```

In `mypage.com/dev.php/mymodel` I get:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | InvalidArgumentException
Your generator configuration contains some errors for the "list" context. The following configuration cannot be parsed: array( 'filters' => array( 0 => 'fklabelid', 1 => '_label_filter', 2 => 'fkrightsownerid', 3 => '_rightsowner_filter', ),).
```

In the **Symfony** page [did not find](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/06-Admin-Generator#chapter_06_actions) good examples this this cases!. Tried many permutations of the 1.0 version. Changing things, adding the **foreign** command in the **config.yml**.

I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT**:

As I was suggested I'm doing the partials. I created a **_Label_list.php**. Redirect the info from the foreign key to the destiny table. In the file, I'm doing something like that:

```
 $rights = RightsOwnerQuery::create()->findPk($MyModel->getFkRightsOwnerId());

 //Print the Info
 echo $rights->getPrice() . ' ('. $rights->getId() . ')';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old `list > filters` in symfony 1.0 have been moved to a dedicated entry `filter` in symfony 1.4.

You now have to use `filter` at the same level of `list`.

```
config:
  actions: ~
  fields:
    fk_label_id: {params: disabled=false}
    fk_rightsowner_id: {params: disabled=false}
  list:            
  //  peer_method:          doSelectJoinAll                         ("commented")
  //  display:              [=_label_list, =_rightsowner_list]      ("commented")
  filter:
    display: [fklabelid, _label_filter, fkrightsownerid, _rightsowner_filter]
  form:    ~
  edit:    ~
  new:     ~
```

By the way, be careful, field started with "_" are partial. So don't forget to create partial (I guess they are already exists in the symfony 1.0).

**Edit:**
About partial, you have to create them in the templates directory of the admin module:

```
modules
  |- rightsownerinlabel
    |- actions
    |- config
      |- generator.yml
    |- lib
    |- templates
      |- _label_filter.php
      |- _rightsowner_filter.php
```

I don't often fo partial for filters, but dig into the generated code in cache folder to see how you can retrieve the FormFilter object and do want ever you want with

Comment: I get an error in "peer_method" :/. It says `Your generator configuration contains some errors for the "list" context. The following configuration cannot be parsed: array( 'peer_method' => 'doSelectJoinAll',)` But I don't see anything wrong. Even if I put `doSelect` which is the default, iot gives me that error.

Comment: And if you removed it ? It used to manually perfom left join on related table. According to the doc, the default is `doSelect`: http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/06-Admin-Generator#chapter_06_sub_peer_method

Comment: I get `Call to undefined method: get_labelList`. I read the doc and mention partials. Nevertheless, It does not say **where** to created it. Read the example of how to do it with **divs**, etc. Could you share a reference for writing partials?! oh god!

Comment: I also read that I must add a `_toString()` method to the classes, so It could print, not a number but the info referred of the number -the fkey-. Have you used something like that?

Comment: I've updated my answer about partial. The `_toString` has to be written in the model class

Comment: Done, I did the partial (edited my original question). It was hard. Using symfony and propel could be an orgy. Thank you!